# How to get all up-coming appointments in outlook in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to add a progress bar for exporting all appointments to a database in outlook with a Macro.

Here is my VBA code:

```
For Each appointment In objFolder.Items
     If appointment.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice Then
         total = total + 1
     End If
Next
```

With this code, `total` stays at `0` so I cant get a percentage.

I don't know how to use the debugger.  I would like to see what the variable is when it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article.

Instead of iterating over all items in the folder you can use the [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) or [Find/FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Items class. They will allow to find only those items that correspond to your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough code to see what the problem could be. Perhaps you are not pointing to a calendar. Following the pattern of your code, without attempting to make it more efficient...

```
Option Explicit

Sub countAp()
Dim objfolder As folder
Dim Appointment As AppointmentItem
Dim totalAll As Long
Dim total As Long

Set objfolder = Application.GetNamespace("mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

For Each Appointment In objfolder.Items
    If Appointment.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice Then
        totalAll = totalAll + 1
    End If
Next

Debug.Print "All Appointment.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice: " & totalAll

Debug.Print "Processing..."

For Each Appointment In objfolder.Items
    If Appointment.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice Then
        ' do something here
        Debug.Print Appointment.Subject
        total = total + 1
        Debug.Print " current total: " & Format(total, "000") & _
          "  Percentage Complete: " & Format(total / totalAll * 100, "##0.00")
    End If
Next

Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub
```

You will find this helpful [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)